# Galvanic corrosion in heating system

Tags: corrosion

I’m a training heating engineer and have am unsure on hydrogen build-up in heating systems. I understand that any free air and the water within a heating system will react with the iron content in steel radiators and cause a build-up of sludge (magnetite) as well as hydrogen as another by-product, is this correct?

Secondly is hydrogen produced as a by-product from galvanic corrosion in a heating system between two dissimilar metals? I understand you need two dissimilar metals, an electrolyte and a conductive path between the metals for corrosion to take place. Is oxygen required for galvanic corrosion and does the water break down during this process releasing hydrogen?